# Need of Service mesh in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

When DNS service Discovery in kubernetes  helping us in establishing connection between services . What will be the need to have a service mesh like istio etc in kubernetes.

Comment: this is like apple and oranges

Comment: Hello @ljaz ,  can you please help me to understand it better with more context.

Comment: Istio is addressing a list of other things that has nothing to do with DNS

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the service discovery, few other things are available when you use Istio on top of Kubernetes:

- Blue green deployments with request routing to new release based on percentage value given by user.
- Rate limiting
- Integration with grafana and prometheus for monitoring
- Service graph visualisation with Kiali
- Circuit breaking
- Tracing and metrics without having to instrument your applications
- You will be able to secure your connections at mesh level via mTLS

You can read more about the advantages of [having Istio in your cluster here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/istio-why-do-i-need-it-18d122838ee3).